# DoxBox start from C#

Tags: c#, process

I try to start DoxBox from my console application, but it simply do nothing. What can be a problem?

```
Process proc = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startinfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startinfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\DoxBox";
startinfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
string strComm = "DoxBox.exe /dismount H:";
startinfo.Arguments = strComm;
proc.StartInfo = startinfo;
proc.Start();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you start the procces with `cmd.exe`?
It isn't in your `C:\\Program Files (x86)\\DoxBox` directory, I'm sure.

Provide the DoxBox file in the `FileName`, without `cmd.exe` at all:

```
Process proc = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startinfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startinfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\DoxBox";
startinfo.FileName = "DoxBox.exe";
string strComm = "/dismount H:";
startinfo.Arguments = strComm;
proc.StartInfo = startinfo;
proc.Start();
```

Comment: Argh! Beat me to it =P

Comment: @user959631 Try harder :P

Comment: I copied doxbox.exe to my project and it worked. Thanks!